# .NET 6 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Linq, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, migration, .net-6.0

I am trying to migrate a project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.
I have followed the [official migration guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

During build in startup.Configure I get

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Linq, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

This is .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <AssemblyName>Omicron.Insurance.Runner</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Omicron.Insurance.Runner</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Omicron.Insurance.Entities" Version="1.0.139" />
    <PackageReference Include="Omicron.Platform.Web.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.1.60" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.22" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin" Version="6.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: tried to add it manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to update `AzureFunctionsVersion` from `v3` to `v4`. That solved the issue.
Upgrading Azure Functions wasn't mentioned in the official migration guide from Microsoft.

EDIT: you also need to upgrade the Azure Function App as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#migrating-from-3x-to-4x

Comment: This is not only ```<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>``` in project file, but also needs to upgrade on the Azure functtion app > Configuration ```FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION``` to 4.

Comment: Good point. Edited the answer to include that part as well.

Comment: Hi. I am also facing similar error. I have updated AzureFunctionVersion to v4 as well function extension version to 4. And have updated net-framework-version to 6. Do I need to something else also?

Answer (score 1):

My case is different from the OP's but I want to share it for information. I run into this error when I try to use dnSpy to patch a C# DLL. It turns out the dnSpy compilation is targeting dependencies of my development machine. When I move the compiled DLL to the target machine, this error is raised as the dependencies are not met there. I have to compile it again on my target machine and the error is gone.